# Сортировка записей с помощью произвольных полей

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

В WP имеется произвольное поле `top_partner (true/false)`, я хочу чтобы все записи на странице сортировались по этому полю, если `true` то эти записи сверху, если `false` то записи снизу.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
                           'post_type' => 'partner',
                           'posts_per_page' => -1,
                           'meta_key'=> 'top_partner',
                           'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                           'order' => 'DESC',
                           'tax_query' => array(
                                               array(
                                                   'taxonomy' => 'partner-city',
                                                   'field' => 'term_id',
                                                   'terms' => $category->term_id,
                                                   //'operator'=> 'NOT IN'
                                                     )
                                               )
                                         )
                                         );

                    $posts = $cat = array();
                    while ($query->have_posts()) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        //the_post();
                        $post = $query->post;                           
                        //$taxonomies = wp_get_post_categories($post -> ID); print_r($post); exit;
                        $categories = get_the_terms($post -> ID, 'partner-city');
                        if(count($categories) > 0){
                            foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
                                if($value->parent==$category->term_id || $value->term_id==$category->term_id)
                                $posts[$value->name][] = $post;
                            }
                        }else                            
                        $posts[$category->name][] = $post;

                    }
```

но так у меня отображаются только записи в которых `top_partner` стоит в тру.
что надо изменить для того чтобы отображало и остальные записи?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
                           'post_type' => 'partner',
                           'posts_per_page' => -1,
                           'meta_key'=> 'top_partner',
                           'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                           'order' => 'DESC',
                           'meta_query' => array(
                              array(
                                'key' => 'top_partner',
                                'value' => array(true, false),
                                'type' => 'BOOLEAN',
                              ),
                           )
                           'tax_query' => array(
                                               array(
                                                   'taxonomy' => 'partner-city',
                                                   'field' => 'term_id',
                                                   'terms' => $category->term_id,
                                                   //'operator'=> 'NOT IN'
                                                     )
                                               )
                                         )
                                         );
```

Comment: изменил, но это не помогло

Comment: @AntonKucenko вывело тоже самое без false или что-то другое и в каком порядке?

Comment: тоже самое без false, делал по документации, не понимаю почему не работает

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

Comment: @AntonKucenko если это acf то у Вас все верно, причина в чем-то другом

Comment: если убрать meta_key = top_partner то записи выходят в не отсортированном виде, а после этого кода который я предоставил идет просто перебор этих записей циклом

Comment: @AntonKucenko попробуйте так, обновил ответ

Comment: эффект тот же, возможно что то не так с полем? я добавил фото к вопросу

Comment: @Anton Kucenko с полем все хорошо, буду смотреть еще,  в чем причина

Comment: а может ли быть такое, что поле отправляет  не false а null??

Comment: @Anton Kucenko попробуйте 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

Comment: @Anton Kucenko не должно быть true/false, а так нужно дебажить

Comment: Ничего не происходит, ещё я изменил поле и указал значение по умолчанию в true (галочку установил) в надежде, что отобразятся все записи, но увы все как прежде) совсем не понимаю почему так

Comment: @Anton Kucenko а по других полях пробывали? Тоесть не по boolean?

Comment: решил таким способом: создал другое поле select и в коде сделал 2 запроса получения записей с true и с записями false затем объединил это в один массив и все прекрасно заработало) Спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: @AntonKucenko просто очень странно почему не работало. Хорошо что нашли выход)